# Is it possible for a firm does not have shutdown point?

Tags: microeconomics, theory-of-the-firm

If a firm has a quadratic cost function, is it means that the firm does not have shut down point and never shut down? Are the changes in fixed cost do not affect the firm's shutdown decision?

Answer (score 2):

$TC(q)=10+3q+0.5q^2$ is a quadratic cost function and has a shutdown point at $P=3$.

Comment: I suspect by quadratic the OP means $TC(q) = q^2 + F$.

Comment: @Giskard: That's plausible. But even then a shutdown point still exists, albeit a rather uninteresting one. Let's wait and see if OP comes to clarify this.